# html5 video tag subtitles srt won't work

Tags: html, html5-video

I'd like to use captions with an mp4 video downloaded from Youtube.  I also used googlesrt2 to create an .srt file from the youtube link.  This is the html I am using:

```
<video controls="controls" height="480" width="640"> 
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video1.mp4" /> 
    <track kind="captions" src="output1.srt" srclang="en">
</video>
```

Ironically, it works in all browsers sans the actual captions, except for IE where it doesn't work at all (I thought IE native was mp4!).
I'm rather frustrated and not sure how to fix this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution : You have to use JS to sync subtitles with video track for all platforms.

```html
<script src="http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/includes/videosub-0.9.9.js"></script>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://mkvtoolnix.download/samples/vsshort-aac.mkv" type="video/mp4">
  <track kind="captions" src="https://mkvtoolnix.download/samples/vsshort-en.srt" srclang="en">                         
</video>
```